# Select value from input field within the div that was clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of divs that all have unique input fields containing different values that I need to grab using jQuery.

Below is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $(".container").click(function() {
                var input_field = $("a.container .input_field).val();   
                input_field = $.trim(input_field);
                        });
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<a class="container">
<input class="input_field" value="132"/>
</a>

<a class="container">
<input class="input_field" value="674"/>
</a>

<a class="container">
<input class="input_field" value="35fd2"/>
</a>
```

Comment: What is your problem ? What do you want to do ? (and btw, you have a missing quote in your selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".container").click(function() {
        var input_field = $(this).find(".input_field").val();   
        input_field = $.trim(input_field);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I know it had something to do with using (this) instead of the class name. I didn't know you could attach a .val to the end of a .find. THANKS MAN!

Comment: I will but it makes me wait 10min.

Answer (score 0):

you should use names and types for your inputs

if you have wrapped your inputs in any other identified element, you can call for example something like:

```
var values = $('#my-form').serialize();
```

i don't know what's your goal - what do you need these values for?

Comment: I outlined the issue in the first line of the question. isherwood provided me with the correct solution. thanks for your help though